# @ionic-native/sqlite not working in visual studio

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic2, visual-studio-2017

I have Ionic 2 project in macOS, using Visual  Studio Code to edit, and ionic cli command line commands to compile and run it. It was working, fine, but now I want to edit this project in my windows PC, using Visual Studio 2017. For that, I created a new project using Ionic 2 template available in visual studio, and then copied the source code from mac to this new project. I notice one thing: In MacOs, SQLite was referenced throught the following command:

```
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
```

But visual studio was not recognizing this reference, even after installing sql lite plugin. Visual Studio offer a command to include the import command to me, when I did that, it added the following sentence:

```
import { SQLite } from "ionic-native/dist/es5";
```

why are this commands different between mac and pc? I'd like it to be the same, so i could edit the same code in Mac and PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These commands shouldn't be different between mac and pc. There are two steps neccessary to install the SQLLite Plugin:

```
1) ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage
2) npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite
```

At first please check if you find the folling package in your node_modules folder:

```
node_modules\@ionic-native\sqlite
```

If thats not the case, you should run npm install (step 2).

Otherwise Visual Studio is not referencing your node_modules folder correctly. I'm using VS Code, where you can explicitly specify where your node_modules folder is (if its not already imported)

Comment: That solved my problem. I added the plugin through visual studio, but wasn't able to reference it in code. But after a did a "nom install --save..." it was all ok.